# Django applying custom user permissions

Tags: python, django

I am currently using this method to feed a user the page relevant to them.

```
def get_user_url(request):
    un = request.user.username
    t = get_template(un + '.htm')
    html = t.render()
    return HttpResponse(http)
```

I was only expecting a small number of users, each representing a company, so this was not a problem as I could simply have five or six html files with different content.
Now I have been asked to account for multiple users per company, assuming differing permissions for users under the same company.

So I looked at the docs for custom permissions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions which could work but I might end up with a permissions class with 30 lines looking like below and that strikes me as a bad way to do it.

```
permissions = (
        ("company1_permission1", "Company 1 Permission 1"),
        ("company1_permission2", "Company 1 Permission 2"),
        ("company2_permission1", "Company 1 Permission 1"),
        ("company2_permission2", "Company 1 Permission 2"),
        ("company3_permission1", "Company 1 Permission 1"),
    )
```

Is there a way I could add a 'company' field to users and use both the above methods? So the user does not even get to a page unless they are from the right company. Then in that page I apply my custom permissions to the content on that page.

Alternatively is there a better method of achieving this sort of functionality.
I am new to django and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution is to use the [`@user_passes_test()` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test).

The docs give a good example for making sure a user's email is from a specific company, which you can easily adapt for your use case:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def email_check(user):
    return user.email.endswith('@example.com')

@user_passes_test(email_check)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

The main problem with this approach is that you can't access the `request` object in your code. A solution would be to use Class Based Views where the `UserPassesTestMixin` gets access to `self.request`.

Comment: is this problem not solved by my_view(request) though?

Comment: Yes that can solve it. You just can't access the `request` object in your `email_check` code...just the current `user` object there.